# Optimisation of two parameters.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

I would like to optimize firstly $D >0$ then $K\in \mathbb{N}$ to get this inequality
$$
\frac{TL}{K^{\beta}} + DT + 3KL + \frac{16K\log(T)}{D} \le C_{L,\beta} T^{\frac{\beta +1}{2\beta+1}} \log(T)^{\frac{\beta}{2\beta+1}} 
$$
with $\beta \in ]0;1]$, $L>0$, $T \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$.

I attempt was to say that $T\ge 3$ otherwise it's complicated, maybe we can do better, surely. And then I chosed $D = \log(T)^{\frac{1}{2(2\beta+1)}}LT^{\frac{-1}{2\beta+1}} $ then $K = \left \lfloor \sqrt{T^{1-\frac{1}{2\beta+1}} } \right \rfloor + 1$ so $C_{\beta,L} = 42L$

It's weird there's no $\beta$ in $C_{\beta,L}$ ! That's why I'm here, I would like to learn how to deal with those kind of question because my method was really... Wild !

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My following straightforward approach provides a similar bound.

Denote the left hand side of the inequality by $A$.

Assume first that $T>1$, so $\log T>0$. Then, by AM-GM inequality, $DT+\frac{16K\log T}{D}$ is minimized when $DT=\frac{16K\log T}{D}$, that is $D=\sqrt{\frac{16K\log T}{T}}$ and the minimum value equals $8\sqrt{KT\log T}$. Now $A$ becomes $\frac{TL}{K^{\beta}} +  3KL +8\sqrt{KT\log T}$. 
The calculation of the exact minimum of this expression with respect to $K$ looks complicated, so we’ll try to obtain possible weaker, but simpler bounds as follows. Remark that
$\frac{TL}{K^{\beta}} +  3KL +8\sqrt{KT\log T}\le (L+1)\left(\frac{T}{K^{\beta}} +  3K +8\sqrt{KT\log T}\right)$.

Asymptotic evaluations suggest to pick $K=\left(\frac{T}{\log T}\right)^{\frac 1{1+2\beta}}$ (this value can be non-integer, but I expect that if we change $K$ to a closest integer value then the expression will not change much). Then

$\frac{T}{K^{\beta}} +  3K +8\sqrt{KT\log T}=9T^{\frac{\beta+1}{2\beta+1}}(\log T)^ {\frac{\beta}{2\beta+1}}+3T^{\frac 1{1+2\beta}}(\log T)^{-\frac 1{1+2\beta}}$.

If $T=1$ then $A=\frac{L}{K^{\beta}} + D + 3KL$. If we pick $K=1$ and $D=L$ then $A=5L$.

Comment: What do you mean by an Asymptotic evaluations suggest ?

Comment: @CechMS This is a good question. I estimated the summands of the expression $\frac{T}{K^{\beta}} +  3K +8\sqrt{KT\log T}$
for big $T$. For this first I picked $K=T^\alpha$, $\alpha>0$ and obtained that summands are of degrees  $1-\alpha\beta$,
$\alpha$ and $(1+\alpha)/2$, respectively. Since $\beta\le 1$, the value $\alpha=1$ assures  that all these degrees 
are at most $1$. If $\alpha<1$ then $(1+\alpha)/2>\alpha$ so we have to minimize the larges degree among $1-\alpha\beta$ and 
$(1+\alpha)/2$.

Comment: Since when $\alpha$ increases, the first degree decreases and  the second increases, required $\alpha$ satisfies the equality $1-\alpha\beta=(1+\alpha)/2$, that is $\alpha=\tfrac 1{1+2\beta}$. When I plugged $K=T^\alpha$ in the expression, I found that we can balance the first and the third summands even more, adjusting $K=T^\alpha$ by a multiplier $(\log T)^{-\gamma}$. The exact value of $\gamma$ was found similarly to the exact value of $\alpha$ above.